# OpenID steam session managing

Tags: node.js, session

Since it is my first time with sessions and openID I'm going through this blindly. I think I got it managed with express-session and having sessions stored in mongodb site.
 What I am actually trying to do is let people log on the site and once they get back have this session active (so I can compare it somehwere in Angular (if someone is logged, take their id, show special content for them). Or let the login button disappear once they logged.

Here's part of my code handling sessions, I don't even know if its working correctly beside it gives no errors.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var util = require('util');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);


var app = express();

var store = new MongoDBStore(
    {
      uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/connect_mongodb_session_test',
      collection: 'mySessions'
    }
);


store.on('error', function(error) {
  assert.ifError(error);
  assert.ok(false);
});

app.use(require('express-session')({
  secret: 'Rbt jest cool',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 // 1 week
  },
  store: store,
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

var OpenIDStrategy = require('passport-openid').Strategy;
var SteamStrategy = new OpenIDStrategy({
  providerURL: 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid',
  stateless: true,
  returnURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/steam/return',
  realm: 'http://localhost:3000/'
},
    function(identifier, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        var user = {
          identifier: identifier,
          steamId: identifier.match(/\d+$/)[0]
        };
        console.log(user);
        return done(null, user);
      });
      console.log(identifier);
    });

passport.use(SteamStrategy);

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) {
  done(null, user.identifier);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(identifier,done) {
  done(null, {
    identifier: identifier,
    steamId: identifier.match(/\d+$/)[0]
  });
});
```

Any idea how can I now take the user and compare if he's logged in angular? Then hide or show content depending on it. Also once user is logged I would like to update record somewhere else in database. Any guidance is appreciated, greatly.

Comment: You ever a working example?

Comment: @Garuuk Unfortunately not, I don't have access to any of those files now. I'm pretty sure you could find something by searching "openid session managament nodejs". Can't help you more, good luck!

Comment: I actually got this working with my setup using express sessions and mongo session storage. Let me know if you'd like more information

Comment: @Garuuk I actually wasn't the person at the end who implemented that, so if you have some spare time and would like to share with me how you handled that it would be great :). But if that will take too much of your time, then there's no need beside my curiosity.